# How to do a match with div with a custom-data of 'x' to a json object with the same value of 'x'?

Tags: json, each, matching

I am not sure if this is achievable.

I have a list of `li` that all has a custom attribute with an unique value. I also have a JSON file that has a list of objects. Each object has a specific field that has the same value

**Problem:** I am trying to match the `li` attribute 'x' with the value 'x' inside the JSON. If that match is correct I want to grab all the fields inside the same object as 'x' and place it inside the `li` with attribute 'x'.

Please help, I am not sure how to start this. I will need some sample or even a jsfiddle example.

**JSON Structure**

```css
[
    {
        "word": "hello",
        "favnumber": "0070",
        "item": "item1",
        "color": "red"
   },
   {
        "word": "hello world",
        "favnumber": "0233070",
        "item": "item2",
        "color": "blue"
   },
   {
        "word": "hello mom",
        "favnumber": "0070",
        "item": "item3",
        "color": "pink"
   },
   {
        "word": "hello dad",
        "favnumber": "0070",
        "item": "item4",
        "color": "silver"
   }
```

]

**HTML Structure**

```html
<div>

  <li data-item="item1">1</li>
  <li data-item="item2">2</li>
  <li data-item="item3">3</li>
  <li data-item="item4">4</li>

</div>
```

**HTML New Structure**

```html
<div>

  <li data-item="item1">hello , 0070, item1, red</li>
  <li data-item="item2">hello world, 0233070, item2, blue</li>
  <li data-item="item3">hello mom, 231213, item3, pink</li>
  <li data-item="item4">hello dad, 007021312, item4, silver</li>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the overall task into simple sub-steps:

1. Query the DOM tree to extract the elements that have certain attributes (in your case, `[data-item=*]`).
2. For each of those elements, get the `data-item` attribute's value.
3. Loop through the JSON object, that represents an array, to find the element of this array respective to the DOM element found at the previous step.
4. Replace the DOM element's child text node to arbitrary value.

Let's walk through it.

## Query the DOM tree to find elements with certain attributes

This is achieved with the help of `document.querySelectorAll` DOM API. The method takes the selector as its first parameter, pretty similar to what you'd write in CSS:

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('[data-item]');
```

Now, inside `items` variable, you have a `NodeList` of elements. First step done.

## Get the attribute value for every element

This is simple and can be done with something like

```
var name = items[0].getAttribute('data-item');
```

Now the `name` var stores a string that represents the `[data-item]`'s attribute value.

Since you have an array of `NodeList` elements, you have to loop through it:

```
for (var e in items) {
    var element = items[e];
    var name = element.getAttribute('data-item');
    //...
}
```

## Find the element in data array by element's property value

Now you have to put a loop into a loop so you can find an element that concurs with the element.

Like this:

```
for (var e in items) {
    var element = items[e];
    var name = element.getAttribute('data-item');

    for (var i in data) {
        var item = data[i];
        // ...
    }
}
```

Here, the `item` variable stores an object, one of many within the initial JSON array (named `data` in this particular example).

Next, you have to check if the `item` is one you need or not. In you case,

```
if (name == item.item) {
    //...
}
```

because `item`'s property `item` stores the value that has to concur with the value of `[data-item]` attribute of the DOM element.

Now, finally...

## Replace the value

You may need something more specific to your task, but this example shows a simple `element.innerText` replacement.

Let's pretend you're within the `if` statement and its condition evaluated to true. Next, you want to do something like

```
var text = [];
text.push(item.word);
text.push(item.favnumber);
text.push(item.item);
text.push(item.color);

element.innerText = text.join(", ");
```

---

And that's it, basically.

You can see how the whole snippet works in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3r4rmLth/

Comment: Also, this whole code runs in `O(N^2)` time but you can reduce it slightly to `O(N^2/2)` by popping out the values of inner loop's array (i.e. mutating it) using `Array.prototype.splice` method, however, I'm not sure it will lead to significant advantage.

Comment: Hi Rishat Muhametshin , great documentation on how it works. I got it to work and I understand it until the last part. I am trying to change the logic a bit where I want to push the 'items' to 'specific' class within the 'element'. For some reason I can't get it to work.

Comment: Hi @RishatMuhametshin, I was able to inject value into specific elements. Now I am trying to extend the JSON to have sub value, but for some reason it says the value is undefined. Would know why ? jsfiddle.net/icovermaface/24L02a1q

Comment: This happens because the first element in `data` array doesn't have `Promo` property. Later in code, you're trying to evaluate `item.Promo.Price` which, since `item.Price` is `undefined`, throws a `TypeError` exception. I'd recommend you acquire Google Chrome Developer Tools, it's a good thing  for a front-end developer to rely on.